# const and let as param in function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    const startDate= moment(startDate);
    const stopDate = moment(stopDate); // doesn't work
}
```

This won't work duplicate declaration. Either it will work if I change const to let. It's hard to rename it coz the param name is exactly what it means. Sometime I prefer `var` but expert said should ditch var and use only const and let hmm.

Comment: Remove the `const`. The variables already exist, so you can just use `stopDate = moment(stopDate)`.

Comment: The reason is the name of variable inside function and parameter is same.

Comment: what is the general purpose of this function? Does it return new dates?

Answer (score 0):

In the function parameter you already create the variables `startDate`, `stopDate`.
So now you can update the variables but can't create new variable with same name.

Also try to learn about JavaScript Hoisting and about the difference of ES5 vs ES6.
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-what-is-hoisting-in-javascript-a63c1b2267a1